# Как выбрать все значение, которые отвечают по фильтру на SQLAlchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
ResSeats.query.filter_by(res_id=id).first()
```

вот код, который выбирает первый совпадавшую строку. А мне нужно, чтобы выбрать все совпадающие строки по фильтру.

Comment: ResSeats.query.filter_by(res_id=id).all()

Comment: как потом выбрать мне нужный столбец? если выбрать колонну res_id вот так res.res_id тогда выдает ошибку. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'res_id'

Comment: print(session.query(ResSeats.res_id).filter_by(res_id=id).all()) или [x.res_id for x in ResSeats.query.filter_by(res_id=id).all()]